# Divide Canvas Arc To 364 Days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

My question is how to divide countdown days circular to 364 days, I mean when the number of remaining days is equal 364 days make circular like this:

[image]

and when the number of remaining days is equal 0 days make circular like this:

[image]

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    var settings = {
      'date': null
    };
    if (options) {
      $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    this_sel = $(this);
    /*Canvas JavaScript*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 100;


    var sec_arc_end = 0,
      min_arc_end = 0,
      hour_arc_end = 0,
      day_arc_end = 0;

    function count_exec() {
      eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
      currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
      if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        callback.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

      days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

      seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
      hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
      seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
      minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds -= minutes * 60;

      // seconds arc canvas...................
      context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      sec_arc_end = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10472));
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + sec_arc_end, false);
      context.lineWidth = 8;
      context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context.stroke();

      // minutes arc canvas...................
      context1.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      min_arc_end = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));
      context1.beginPath();
      context1.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min_arc_end, false);
      context1.lineWidth = 8;
      context1.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context1.stroke();
        // hours arc canvas...................

      context2.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
      context2.beginPath();
      context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context2.lineWidth = 8;
      context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context2.stroke();
        // days arc canvas...................
        // the problem is here
      context3.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      day_arc_end = ((- days) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
      context3.beginPath();
      context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + day_arc_end, false);
      context3.lineWidth = 8;
      context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context3.stroke();
      // add 0 value to left of value
      if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
        this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
        this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
        this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
      }
    }
    count_exec();
    console.log(days);
    interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);
  };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "18 january 2017 12:34:00"
    },
      function () {
          $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
      }
    );
    $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
    });
})
```

```css
#countdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.countdown-container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 97%;
  text-align: center;
}
#countdown .countdown-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.30% 0.5% 0.30% 0.5%;
}
#countdown .countdown-container .contents {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}
.contents div {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.contents span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:1px solid #ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="secs">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Seconds</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="mins">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Minutes</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="hours">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Hours</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="days">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Days</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The problem** is here:

```
day_arc_end = ((-days) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));  // the problem is here
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something similar to:

```
// (((365-days)/365)*2 - 0.5)*Math.PI
context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -0.5*Math.PI, (((365-days)/365)*2 - 0.5)*Math.PI, false);
```

Basically html canvas arc() begins drawing from (1, 0) in a unit cartesian or 3:00 if you look at the circle like a clock. Full circle is 1.5*Math.PI.

so 12:00 is -0.5*Math.PI, 03:00 is 0*Math.PI etc.

So in a more verbose way:

```
var percentageOfYear = (365-days)/365;
var fullCircleRads = 2*Math.PI;
var ending_arc = percentageOfYear*fullCircleRads - 0.5*Math.PI;
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_arc.asp

Comment: hank you for Helping me, You have helped me to understand more and more, another problem occurred when I change the radius, I Edit the Code Above to See Problem. please Run Snippet in Full Page. Thank You

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn html canvas doesn't reset or clear itself on each frame. So everything that you draw, draws on top of everything else. So by changing the radius of the circle, the gray rectangle you use for the text is smaller and doesn't clear the previous graphics. To fix this, make the rectangle bigger cover the canvas (at least cover the circle). Or on each frame have a rectangle cover everything in canvas as a background before everything else.
And don't worry about performance. Html canvas is not photoshop. You just overwrite the pixels, so no memory overhead.